# Zombie.js in node.js fails to scrape certain websites

Tags: javascript, node.js, screen-scraping, zombie.js

The simple script below returns a bunch of rubbish. It works for most websites, but not william hill:

```
var Browser = require("zombie");
var assert = require("assert");

// Load the page from localhost
browser = new Browser()
browser.visit("http://sports.williamhill.com/bet/en-gb/betting/y/5/et/Football.html", function () {
browser.wait(function(){
console.log(browser.html());
});
});
```

run with node

output:

S����J����ꪙRUݒ�kf�6���Efr2�Riz�����^��0�X�
��{�^�a�yp��p�����Ή��`��(���S]-��'N�8q�����/���?�ݻ��u;�݇�ׯ�Eiٲ>��-���3�ۗG�Ee�,��mF���MI��Q�۲������ڊ�ZG��O�J�^S�C~g��JO�緹�Oݎ���P����ET�n;v������v���D�tvJn��J�8'��햷r�v:��m��J��Z�nh�]�� ����Z����.{Z��Ӳl�B'�.¶D�~$n�/��u"�z�����Ni��"ǋ��\00_I\00\��S��O�E8{"�m;�h��,o��Q�y��;��a[������c��q�D�띊?��/|?:�;��Z!}��/�wے�h�<�������%������A�K=-a��~'

(actual output is much longer)

Anyone know why this happens, and specifically why it happens on the only site i actually want to scrape???

Thanks

Comment: Check the headers; you may be getting DEFLATEd or gzipped data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have abandoned this method long ago, but in case anyone is interested I got a reply from one of the zombie.js devs.

https://github.com/assaf/zombie/issues/251#issuecomment-5969175

He says: "Zombie will now send accept-encoding header to indicate it does not support gzip."

Thank you all who looked into this.

Answer (score 0):

The same code works for other sites (which also use gzip to reply) so it's not a code problem.

My guess is the site is detecting that you are not running a browser and defending against data extraction.

Comment: Defend against data extraction by sending binary response? Unlikely.

Comment: I also think that to be unlikely. I'm reasonably sure that the response is the gzipped equivalent to the page I download, I just need a way of unzipping it.